# ClassMetaData.getPropertyValue() throws LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, hibernate, metadata, hibernate-session

I am trying to get a property value from the class meta data by calling

`getPropertyValue(Object object , String propertyName , EntityMode entityMode)`

but it is throwing a

`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` exception, here is my code:

```
ClassMetaData metaData = sessionFactory.getClassMetaData(myObject.getClass());
for(String propertyName : metaData.getPropertyNames()){
    Object propertyValue = metaData.getPropertyValue(myObject, propertyName, EntityMode.POJO);
    System.out.println(propertyValue);
}
```

It is printing the first object value, and starting from the second run, it is throwing the exception.

Comment: So wrap it in a Transaction

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of lazy loading is , when you close session or flush changes .. You get only data which is already in session . if you don't invoke any object for which association is defined as lazy loading and after flushing if you try to invoke it, It thows same error what you are getting. The solutions for this would be change lazy load into eager or load the object by invoking it before closing the session or flushing the data